# Cannot add bar button to UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to create a static footer in my application. i used UIToolbar. Now i want to add some buttons with custom photos to it. the toolbar works fine but it does not show the buttons.

Here is the code i used to add the buttons:

```
UIImage *facebookImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"facebook.png"];
UIImage *twitterImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"twitter.png"];
UIImage *messageImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"message.png"];
UIImage *emailImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"email.png"];


UIBarButtonItem *facebook=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:facebookImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:Nil action:Nil];
UIBarButtonItem *twitter=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:twitterImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:Nil];
UIBarButtonItem *message=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:messageImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:Nil];
UIBarButtonItem *email=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:emailImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:Nil];

NSArray *toolbarButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: facebook, twitter,email,message, nil];
[Footer setItems:toolbarButtons];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code change :

```
UIImage *facebookImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"facebook.png"];
UIImage *twitterImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"twitter.png"];
UIImage *messageImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"message.png"];
UIImage *emailImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"email.png"];
```

with :

```
UIImage *facebookImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIImage *twitterImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"];
UIImage *messageImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message.png"];
UIImage *emailImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"email.png"];
```

If you want to use `- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` method you should get the full pathname of the file :

```
NSString* Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_file_name" 
                                            ofType:@"the_file_extension"];
```

Comment: Ok it displays the images but it only shows its borders! the image is a flat design button, but only the border is shown with no color!

Comment: In all buttons or only the facebook one ? can i have one image to use it ?

Comment: @user3687 That's another problem not related to this one. Please, accept the correct answer and solve your next problem. Try not to ask new question, but search the Internet for existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In Following code i added two  `UIBarButton` with **flexSpace**..
**you can add UIBarButton as you want**

```
UIToolbar *Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    Toolbar = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

     NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Cancel)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done)];
    [barItems addObject:btnDone];

    [Toolbar setItems:barItems animated:NO];
```

**Following Method is call when tapped on bar Button**

```
-(void)Cancel
{
  // Write Code for Cancel Method
}

-(void)done
{
  // Write Code for Done Method
}
```

Follow my answer and add `UIBarButtonItem` as per your requirement, might be this code is help for you.